# MySQL join on whichever column is not null

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a bunch of columns, but we only need to look at two of them. I'm trying to join another table on this table, but all we know about these two columns is that one will be null and the other won't:

```
client_id | note_id
```

The main table wants to join `client_id` (if not null) on `clients.id` OR `note_id` on `notes.id` if `clients.id` is null.

Comment: I thinks will server you purpose.... Let me know if it works........make necessary change, its very basic.......... select * from YOUR_TABLE t
left outer join clients c ON t.client_id = c.id
left outer join notes n ON t.note_id = n.id
where c.id is not null or n.id is not null

Comment: Are there 3 tables involved: the main table containing `client_id` and `note_id`, `clients` table with column `id`, and `notes` table with column `id`?

Comment: @pgngp Yes, there are 3 tables: `updates` (the main table; this table is to track things like if a client or note was created, updated, or deleted), `clients`, and `notes`. `Updates` has a column for `client_id` and a column for `note_id`, and one of them will be `null` if the other was updated. So basically I want to join whichever row was updated, whether it's in the `clients` table or `notes` table. The purpose of the `updates` table is to keep an activity log of what changes have been made within the application. I'll take a look at your answer as soon as I get home from work today.

Comment: @GaurangDave Your solution worked - I'm not sure if the other answers completely understood what I was trying to do. If you submit it as an official answer I'll upvote and accept. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisClower I am happy to help. I am submitting it. :)

Comment: @ChrisClower Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.  This is very basic query I wrote. Make changes if required.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c ON t.client_id = c.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n ON t.note_id = n.id 
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL OR n.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use coalesce in the join on clause. See demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99911/2.  If client id is null then use note id to join table1 and table2.

```
 Select t1.client_id, t1.note_id,t2.client_id, t2.note_id
 From table1 t1
 Join table2 t2 
 on coalesce(t1.client_id, t1.note_id) =coalesce(t2.client_id, t2.note_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are 3 tables involved (the main table that contains `client_id` and `note_id` columns, `clients` table, and `notes` table), you can use a query such as this:

```
(select * 
 from mainTable inner join clients on mainTable.client_id = clients.id) 
union 
(select * 
 from mainTable inner join notes on mainTable.note_id = notes.id 
 where mainTable.client_id is NULL);
```

The above query contains 2 queries where each query will output rows where the joining column is not null. The results are then combined using `union`.